# Data changing daily in sheets - how to calculate that change (the same field)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a field that changes daily (number of units), ex. today it's 1238 units and tomorrow 2300 units. This change is registered in the same field every day. Is it even possible to count the daily change in a sheet? Or do I have to do it manually?

I was trying to find solution with countif but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

If by "the same field" you mean the same cell, then no, you cannot calculate the change, since the old value is overwritten every day.

You could use Google Apps Script to make daily snapshots and calculate difference based on those values.  Details of the script will depend on your spreadsheet setup and intended result.